# Ubuntu 20.04: valgrind: "memcheck-amd64-linux" closed unexpectedly

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

I was running the valgrind memory leak test in a thread management program and I got this error window while testing. The message is as follows:
"Sorry, the program "memcheck-amd64-linux" closed unexpectedly. Your computer doesn't have enough memory to automatically analyse the problem and send a report to the developers". After the window popped up, the execution was aborted due to a segmentation fault, but it showed some memory leak and if I run the executable without the valgrind test, the segmentation fault does not happen. I couldn't find any answer to this specific error. What may be the problem?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the program you were running and the specific output you got? For example, did valgrind immediately quit, or did it start producing output before it then crashed? And what code were you running under valgrind?

Comment: Valgrind itself does not open any windows - it is a console application. You must be using some GUI (Valkyrie, Qt Creator or something else). Can you run valgrind from a terminal and post the output here?